# Redefinition in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm currently trying to learn inheritance in C++ but haven't gotten the code to work, I'll put the code and the error message below.the constructor for video seems to be causing some problems, I've tried some stuff online but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

video.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class video
{
private:
    string tipoVideo;
    string nombreVideo;
    string genero;
    int calificacion;
    int anioLanzamiento;
    int duracion;
public:
    video(string tipoVideo1, string nombreVideo1, string genero1, int anioLanzamiento1, int duracion1);
    video(string tipoVideo1, string nombreVideo1, string genero1, int calificacion1, int anioLanzamiento1, int duracion1);
    string gettipoVideo();
    string getnombreVideo();
    string getgenero();
    int getcalificacion();
    int getanioLanzamiento();
    int getduracion();
    void changeCalificacion(int cal);
};
```

video.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "video.h"
using namespace std;

video::video(string tipoVideo1, string nombreVideo1, string genero1, int anioLanzamiento1, int duracion1)
{
    tipoVideo = tipoVideo1;
    nombreVideo = nombreVideo1;
    genero = genero1;
    anioLanzamiento = anioLanzamiento1;
    calificacion = 0;
    duracion = duracion1;
}

video::video(string tipoVideo1, string nombreVideo1, string genero1, int calificacion1, int anioLanzamiento1, int duracion1)
{
    tipoVideo = tipoVideo1;
    nombreVideo = nombreVideo1;
    genero = genero1;
    anioLanzamiento = anioLanzamiento1;
    calificacion = calificacion1;
    duracion = duracion1;
}

string video::getnombreVideo()
{
    return nombreVideo;
}

string video::gettipoVideo()
{
    return tipoVideo;
}

string video::getgenero()
{
    return genero;
}

int video::getcalificacion()
{
    return calificacion;
}

int video::getduracion()
{
    return duracion;
}

int video::getanioLanzamiento()
{
    return anioLanzamiento;
}

void video::changeCalificacion(int n)
{
    calificacion = n;
}
```

pelicula.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "video.h"
using namespace std;

class pelicula:public video
{
private:
    string direccion;
public:
    pelicula(string director);
    string getDirector();
};
```

pelicula.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "video.h"
#include "pelicula.h"
using namespace std;


pelicula::pelicula(string director):video(tipoVideo1, nombreVideo1, genero1, anioLanzamiento1, duracion1)
{
    direccion = director;
}

string pelicula::getDirector()
{
    return direccion;
}
```

When trying to compile:

```
In file included from pelicula.h:2,
                 from pelicula.cpp:3:
video.h:4:7: error: redefinition of 'class video'
    4 | class video
      |       ^~~~~
In file included from pelicula.cpp:2:
video.h:4:7: note: previous definition of 'class video'
    4 | class video
      |       ^~~~~
pelicula.cpp: In constructor 'pelicula::pelicula(std::string)':
pelicula.cpp:7:43: error: 'tipoVideo1' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'tipoVideo'?
    7 | pelicula::pelicula(string director):video(tipoVideo1, nombreVideo1, genero1, anioLanzamiento1, duracion1)
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                           tipoVideo
pelicula.cpp:7:55: error: 'nombreVideo1' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'nombreVideo'?
    7 | pelicula::pelicula(string director):video(tipoVideo1, nombreVideo1, genero1, anioLanzamiento1, duracion1)
      |                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                       nombreVideo
pelicula.cpp:7:69: error: 'genero1' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'genero'?
    7 | pelicula::pelicula(string director):video(tipoVideo1, nombreVideo1, genero1, anioLanzamiento1, duracion1)
      |                                                                     ^~~~~~~
      |                                                                     genero
pelicula.cpp:7:78: error: 'anioLanzamiento1' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'anioLanzamiento'?
    7 | pelicula::pelicula(string director):video(tipoVideo1, nombreVideo1, genero1, anioLanzamiento1, duracion1)
      |                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                              anioLanzamiento
pelicula.cpp:7:96: error: 'duracion1' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'duracion'?
    7 | pelicula::pelicula(string director):video(tipoVideo1, nombreVideo1, genero1, anioLanzamiento1, duracion1)
      |                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                                duracion
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, so help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your headers are not protecting themselves against recursive including by either using a header guard, or using non-standard `#pragma once`.

Comment: fwiw, this has nothing to do with inheritance. You can remove all inheritance and the error will stay the same

Comment: Let's look at the first error message: `error: redefinition of 'class video'`. This mentions your `video` class as a whole with no reference to its members. So it would be reasonable to **1)** strip everything out of the class, reducing its definition to `class video {};` and eliminating `video.cpp`, then **2)** re-compile to see if the error persists. *Note that `pelicula.cpp` is mentioned in the error message, so don't eliminate that file, even though it doesn't need anything other than two of its `#include` lines.*

Comment: Also look up "include guards" as an alternative option.  People who advocate `#pragma once` tend to gloss over the fact (since most modern compilers support it) that it is not actually part of standard C or standard C++.    There are real-world advantages and disadvantages with BOTH options.

Answer (score 0):

You include video.h in both pelicula.h and pelicula.cpp; this causes an issue where the compiler thinks there is a naming conflict with two "different" classes called video.

There are different ways to avoid this; the easiest one is to add

> #pragma once

at the beginning of your header files.

Nonetheless, I would remove the #include video.h from pelicula.cpp since it is included in its header file.

Comment: *"this issue is not related to inheritance"* -- It's not directly related to inheritance, but there is an indirect relationship. Using inheritance increases the chance that the same header will be included twice, as can be seen using your code as an example. I'd consider keeping "inheritance" in the title and code to help others find this question (and accept the redirect to the duplicate).

Comment: That a good argument, you are completely right I will remove that suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a header file being `#include`d twice by your source file (once via another header, once directly).   Because of that, the compiler is seeing definitions more than once, hence the errors.

While, in your simple case, you could remove one of the `#include "video.h"`, such problems are harder to fix (in some cases, impossible) in that way when you have several headers, where some headers include other headers.

There are two more general options that don't rely on you removing an `#include`.

Include guards are supported as part of standard C++  (via the preprocessor).   In your header do something like

```
 #ifndef VIDEO_H_INCLUDED
 #define VIDEO_H_INCLUDED

    // content of your header

 #endif
```

This will protect contents of `video.h` from causing problems (e.g. multiple definitions) if it is included more than once.

The downside is that every header must have a *unique* macro.   If two headers use the same macro, other problems occur.   In larger projects (e.g. projects that use third-party libraries) it is necessary to use an approach to avoid such clashes.

There are also concerns due to some macros/identifiers needing to be avoided (e.g. reserved identifiers).  For example, a macro that starts with an `_` followed by an uppercase letter is reserved, so should not be used.

The second option is to add a single `#pragma once` to each header.   Technically, `#pragma once` is NOT part of standard C++.  A lot of people advocate it, since most (possibly now all) modern compilers support it, but it is (like all pragmas) a non-standard hook.   There are also gotchas in more complicated projects (e.g. on unix systems, where the source tree has symbolic links to files or directories containing third-party libraries, `#pragma once` can fail to detect cases where a file is `#include`d more than once with different names).

If you really want to, you can use both options together.

```
 #ifndef VIDEO_H_INCLUDED
 #define VIDEO_H_INCLUDED

 #pragma once

    // content of your header

 #endif
```

This is a bit of a "belts and suspenders" option, but works since the standard requires compilers to ignore pragmas that they do not recognise.